# Python to "find/replace" a string in a .csv file, getting a tracekback name error

Tags: python, csv

Trying to get python to do a "find/replace" for my "test.csv" CSV file, but I am getting the following error when I run the code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/AmazonBookScrapper/cleanup.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open(test.csv, 'r') as f:
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

The Python3 I am running is:

```
import re
with open(test.csv, 'r') as f:
    csv_file = f.read()

find_str = 'audiocassetteprice='
replace_str = ' '
```

new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, csv_file)

new_csv_path = './NewCSV.csv' 
with open(new_csv_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str)

Comment: Are you missing a pair of single quote `'test.csv'`?

Comment: To be more specific, the error you posted is giving you all the information you need. It sees a named object called test and is looking for it, rather than a string named 'test.csv' pointing to a file path. Dig into info on the error next time.